# Foundation 6 - Populating img tag data-interchange using JavaScript not showing images

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to fix some code that is meant to generate the data-interchange values using JavaScript for images in a slider, but I cannot get it to work unless I have a src tag, and even then, the only image to show is whatever I reference in the src tag.

I feel like this should work as it seems to match the setup for data-interchange according to the Foundation docs, and I don't see any errors in the console to indicate a problem.

Here is the code:

```
         var animallink = $('<a></a>').attr('href', animals[randomkeys[a]].link);
                console.dir(animallistitem);

                $('<img />').attr({
                    'data-interchange': '[' + uploaddirectory + animals[randomkeys[a]].images.med + ', small], [' + uploaddirectory + animals[randomkeys[a]].images.med + ', medium],  [' + uploaddirectory + animals[randomkeys[a]].images.lg + ', large]',
                    'class':'orbit-image',
                    'alt': animals[randomkeys[a]].images.alttext
                }).appendTo(animallink);
                var animalcontainer = $('<div></div>').addClass('related__item-content');

                $('<h2>' + dyktext + '</h2>').appendTo(animalcontainer);
                $('<h3></h3>').addClass('related__name').text(nametext + animals[randomkeys[a]].animal).appendTo(animalcontainer);

                if(animals[randomkeys[a]].location != ""){
                    $('<h3></h3>').addClass('related__location').text(locationtext + animals[randomkeys[a]].location).appendTo(animalcontainer);
                }

                var rndnum = Math.round(Math.random() * (animals[randomkeys[a]].animalfacts.length - 1));

                $('<p></p>').addClass('related__description').html(animals[randomkeys[a]].animalfacts[rndnum].replace('\u0026', '&')).appendTo(animalcontainer);
                $('<div></div>').addClass('related__cta').html(morelinktext + ' <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>').appendTo(animalcontainer);

                animalcontainer.appendTo(animallink);

                animallink.appendTo(animallistitem);

                animallistitem.appendTo(animallist);
            });

            var orbit = new Foundation.Orbit($('.related__animal-facts .orbit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies in this case, but it used to be that when adding interchange elements after page load, Foundation had to be reinitialized using `$(document).foundation()`. Although I can find no mention of it in the current docs.